# Expat resident in Ireland and trading Vanguard Index Funds while visiting United States

Tags: usa, taxes, us-citizens, ireland

I'm a US (California) Citizen currently working/living in Ireland on a visa. I am currently in the United States (California) visiting my parents.

I own some index funds on Vanguard.

I want to trade these shares into a different fund on Vanguard.

**Will doing to entitle Ireland to my shares tax wise**

Comment: It's complicated, and I don't know the answer to your question. The answer will require an examination of a) whether you are a tax resident of and domiciled in Ireland (these are separate questions); b) what kinds of gain or loss will occur because of this trade; c) whether the gain or loss are "taxable events" under the Irish tax laws; d) whether the gain or loss are "taxable events" under the US tax laws; and e) the effect of the [US/Ireland Tax Treaty](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/international-businesses/ireland-tax-treaty-documents).